# How to change monodevelop's font size for tab headings?

Tags: monodevelop, font-size

I have [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) running quite well on Linux Fedora 27.  My only real gripe is that some of the IDE text are ridiculously tiny and often challenging to read.  This occurs in the tabs headings and status window.

I looked around in the `Edit | Preferences | Fonts`, but it only has three controls:  Text editor, General pad text, and Output pad text.  These are all set at 10 or 11 point (not 1 or 2 as it would seem to be); changing all of them to larger values did not affect the tiny text areas.

This behavior might be related to the laptop's 4K monitor (3840 x 2160 pixels).  The console text appearing while the system boots is similarly challenging to read.

[image]

Ideas?  Suggestions?

Comment: Is it picking it up from gnome or whatever gui your using?

Comment: @muszeo:  Interesting idea.  It is gnome 3.26 on wayland 1.14.

Comment: @muszeo:  The only way I found to alter gnome's fonts is the GNOME Tweaks 3.26.4 tool.  It has four text categories, none of which affected the tiny text items.  All its other components *were* affected.

Comment: Lol, interesting, at least that proves it is picking up the other sizes from gnome. Humm will have a think....